# Java script not works in safari but works in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

> My HTML code is as below, it works fine in all browsers but not in safari.

```
<input type="file" name="file" style="display:none"  id="file"/>
<div class="prfile_photo_popup">

<input type="button" value="Select A Photo From Computer"  id="profile_upload_button"/>

</div>
```

> My script is as below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){   
    $('#profile_upload_button').click(function(){
    $('#file').click();
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your JS has a couple of errors in it. No `}` for the `document.ready` and no `})` for the inner function. I don't see how that code is working in any browser.

Comment: Its typing mistake dude.Sorry i missed it.

Comment: @Alternatex no its not working in safari. But works in all browsers, also in IE 11 too.

Comment: @VedPandya Maybe it's the version of your jQuery. In fact, one of jQuery's main purposes is to make JavaScript compatible in all browsers so I find it weird that it doesn't work in Safari. Unless your Safari is outdated and your jQuery is version 2+ I cannot see how this might not work.

Comment: Solved ! Just changed css property from display : none to visibility : hidden :)